# Git workflow for committing an output file only occasionally

Tags: git, version-control, latex

I am writing a paper in LaTeX, version-controlling it with Git.
Typically I track only source files (e.g. `.tex`, `.bib` and graphic files that are used in the paper).

Still, I have mixed feeling if and how to track the output `pdf` file.
On the one hand committing it each time is impractical (there are always changes, and it makes cost each commit ~1MB), while on the other it is convenient to be able to instantly get a previous version (also for co-workers, not assuming that they can compile it from the source).

However, as I don't need to *stamp* every minute change of the pdf, committing it once in a while seems to be the best option. Still, I don't know what is the best workflow for such.

(I post my answer, just not to mix it with the content of the question. I ask the question, as I am not sure whether what I'm doing is the best practice.)

Comment: I wouldn't advise committing the PDF at all, though of course that's up to you. What's wrong with simply not `add`ing the PDF unless you decide to commit it at some point? Just leave it with untracked changes most of the time.

Comment: @Chris It's not software project, so almost all time I want to `git commit -a`, not to add the same files each time (see my answer). When it comes to version-controlling output pdfs (e.g. to show co-authors article version which was sent to a journal; they may be not make pdf from source, it or may be less convenient for them than just viewing pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) to make Git assume that the PDF is unmodified. This would let you use `git commit -a` without including your PDF:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged output.pdf

# Commit all modified files (but not output.pdf)
git commit -a
```

When you want to commit changes to the PDF you would have to stop assuming that it's unchanged before you could add it:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged output.pdf
git add output.pdf
git update-index --assume-unchanged output.pdf
git commit
```

Since this last step is somewhat awkward it may make sense to create an alias for it:

```
git config alias.commit-pdf '!git update-index --no-assume-unchanged output.pdf && git add output.pdf && git update-index --assume-unchanged output.pdf && git commit'
```

Now you can do

```
# Commit all modified files (but not output.pdf)
git commit -a

# When necessary, commit your modified PDF
git commit-pdf
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to hard-code the name of the PDF in your alias you could create it like this:

```
git config alias.force-commit '!git update-index --no-assume-unchanged "$1" && git add "$1" && git update-index --assume-unchanged "$1" && git commit'
```

And use it like this:

```
git force-commit output.pdf
```

Comment: I tried but I am getting `fatal: Unable to mark file output.pdf` (the file exists).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal, when do you receive this message? Running which command?

Comment: Running `git commit-pdf`.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal, perhaps `output.pdf` was not in the immediate directory? I've updated my alias not to hard-code the filename. Edit `.git/config` and remove the alias line that was created before, then try the new one. You'll have to use `git force-commit output.pdf` to cause the PDF to get committed.

Comment: OK, it was the issue with the directory. I thought that when being in a particular directory, I should use the same command as if I typed (e.g. `git update-index --assume-unchanged relative_path_to_file`). I changed in the command `output.pdf` to `folder/output.pdf` (absolute path within repository) and it works (BTW: could you also keep the previous `git commit-pdf` in the answer, as I found it useful). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @PiotrMigdal, I have added back the version of the alias with a hard-coded filename.

Answer (score 1):

Workflows I have been playing with are:

Actually commit `pdf` only from time to time (but then I need to be careful with `git commit -a` and `git add .`, so it gets annoying).

Comment: If you're only going to commit the PDF file, make sure the output branch is empty so that you don't have .tex etc files _and_ a derived .pdf file coming from different versions of those files. Why not merge from master to output before running pdflatex? That way the output branch always contains the latest available PDF and the corresponding source files.

Comment: @MagnusBäck I don't want change `.gitignore` file. Other files are not tracked, so `git checkout output` does not change the source files in the working folder.

Comment: What other files do you mean? The contents of .gitignore doesn't affect which files are updated when you switch between branches. Why would you have to change .gitignore on the output branch, and why would that be a problem anyway? You can still commit the PDF file with `git add -f`. Or, just modify .gitignore on the output branch.

Comment: @MagnusBäck My fault. I mindlessly "translated" my Mercurial workflow for that (and it deal in a different way with untracked files but target branch). I changed the answer.